# Android - getLength() on FileDescriptor?

Tags: android, mp3, sd-card, file-descriptor

i have searched a lot but i cant figure out if there is a way to get the **length** and **offset** of a mp3-file loaded from the sdcard ??

```
public void onClick(View v) {
String audioPath = "/sdcard/MP3/" + textView.getText();
File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
FileInputStream fis = null;
     try {
         fis = new FileInputStream(audioPath);
         fd = fis.getFD();
         String samplerateString = null, buffersizeString = null;
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                samplerateString = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);
                buffersizeString = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
          }
          if (samplerateString == null) samplerateString = "44100";
          if (buffersizeString == null) buffersizeString = "512";
          long[] params = {
                fd.getStartOffset(),                                
                fd.getLength(),
                Integer.parseInt(samplerateString),
                Integer.parseInt(buffersizeString)
          };
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

it is the fd.getStartOffset() and the fd.getLength() that are only available on the assetFIleDescriptor .. but the assetFiledescriptor, as I understood, is not able to load a mp3-file from SDCard, right?

Comment: can't you just `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioPath)` ?

Comment: The start offset is 0 and the length is the length of the file (`new File(audioPath).length()`).

Comment: @Blackbelt .. I don't want to use MediaPlayer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
File audioFile = new File(audioPath);
int length = (int) audioFile.length();
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly? .. the audioPath is the absolute path to the mp3-file on SDCARD..